# Was there a battle between lord Krishna and Arjun in Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, arjuna

[Krishna battles Arjuna](http://hindumythologyforgennext.blogspot.in/2012/06/krishna-battles-arjuna-part-1-of-2.html) here is the story about the battle between lord Krishna and Arjun in Mahabharat. But i am not sure whether this is right or wrong information. So i like to know whether any battle was there between them.

Comment: Not sure about why someone down-voted your question..This story is not from original Mahabharata..It seems from Gayopakhyanam (or Prachanda Yadavam), a Telugu play written by Chilakamarti Lakshmi Narasimham in 1890..u might have seen this in some Telgu movies or in some other random stories/videos..

Comment: Sri Krishnarjuna Yudham, a Telugu movie based on the Gayopakhyanam play, plots this story...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The battle between Lord Krishna and Arjuna is not present in the Original Mahabharata.

We don't find the traces of the incident in Bhagavatam or Harivamsha either. This is because it is a fictional work written by a famous Telugu author [Chilakamarti Lakshminarasimham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilakamarti_Lakshmi_Narasimham). The name of the work is ***Gayopakhyanam*** (IAST Gayopākhyānaṃ) or ***Prachanda Yadavam*** (IAST Pracaṇḍa yādavaṃ). It is written in the year 1890.

The plot of the story goes as follows:

> A Gandharva (one of the few divine births) by birth and was a faithful devotee of Krishna. One fine morning-nay, it was the worst morning in his life-while going to Brahmaloka by Vimana (an airbus), chewing the betel leaf unmindfully spitted it out. The red coloured chewings unfortunately fell into Krishna’s coupled palms holding oblatory water to otter to the rising Sun God, chanting the Holy Hymn. Krishna thus disturbed grew wild and instantaneously took a vow ihit the culprit’s head would soon he severed by his Sudarshana Chakra - the unopposed divine weapon. Poor Gaya having
>   come to know of this, and on the trickish advice of Narada, goes and
>   entreats Arjuna to save his (Gaya’s) life, without infomiing him (Ar
>   juna) of Krishna’s vow. After Arjuna promises to save Gaya’s life, then
>   the latter reveals the details, to the utter dismay of Arjuna. However,
>   having once given the word, he keeps up his word, till the end, despite
>   the terrible war that flared up between him and his revered brother-in-
>   law and protector-Krishna and ultimately Lord Shiva’s interference to
>   save the most dangerous situation with a solution agreeble to both.
>
> The sources of the plot are available neither in Bharatam, nor in Bhagavatam could be traced out in Chitrabharatam or Maruttaratcharitra.

Story taken from the book *[Chilakamarti Lakshminarasimham](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=2dzi7x0glOEC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=gayopakhyanam+source&source=bl&ots=wun5ySydMm&sig=jwuUGmJm0kXCTKuFenCyrVVuh6s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7wffcs4nYAhXKOI8KHZ0-CGIQ6AEIPjAF#v=onepage&q=gayopakhyanam%20source&f=false) by V.V.L Narasimha Rao*. [I don't own any copy rights.]